# How fast can I get to Arles from CDG airport?

Tags: trains, cdg, schedule-change

I have to go to Arles from CDG airport (Terminal 2e) upon arrival  at 10:20 AM to catch a river cruise at 4 PM. How many minutes will it take to get to the TGV station?

Can I change ticket time earlier or later if I buy it in advance? I'm not sure what time I'll get to the station;  If I get off the plane and get my baggage early I'd like to catch it sooner.  Or should I buy tickets when I get there?

Comment: If the trains don't work out (and it looks doubtful), you might look into getting another plane ticket from CDG to Marseille or Montpellier and then taking a cab from there.  There's a 12:25–13:50 flight from CDG–MRS that looks promising.

Comment: On what date would that be? Schedules can vary depending on the day of the week or public holidays.

Comment: It may also make sense to get directly to Lyon instead of Paris, depending on where you are arriving from.

Comment: If you fly to Marseille, you can also get a short bus journey from Marseille airport to Vitrolles Aéroport Marseille station and a direct train to Arles.

Answer (score 2):

That's gonna be impossible to make,

Looking at [SNCF-Connect](https://sncf-connect.com) the only trip that arrive before 4pm in Arles leave CDG at 9:59am.

> Can I change ticket time earlier or later if I buy it in advance?

Usually, you can exchange a ticket for 19€/exchange in a 6-day period preceding your trip (Exchanges are free and unlimted beforehand)

This of course depends on the ticket class you book, if you book a *Business Première* ticket, all exchanges are free up to train departure (but that's by far the most expensive option)

> Or should I buy tickets when I get there?

Buy in advance, tickets to Southern France are sought after a lot and sell out very quickly

> If I get off the plane and get my baggage early I'd like to catch it sooner.

The only connection you *could* catch is at noon, but that arrives at 4:44pm. But, even that is short, entry immigration can be **lengthy** at CDG and can take well over an hour.

> How many minutes will it take to get to the TGV station?

The TGV station is very close to 2E, but I'd let a 15 min walk for it depending where you arrive

Comment: If the OP can make it to the Gare de Lyon by 11:20 then [there's an itinerary that could work](https://www.sncf.com/en/booking-itinerary/itinerary/results-list/details?uic1=OCE87686006&coordX1=&coordY1=&uic2=OCE87753657&coordX2=&coordY2=&date=1686042018&when=leave-at&id=54213660&typeDepart=ZONE_ARRET&typeArrivee=ZONE_ARRET&label1=Paris%20-%20Gare%20de%20Lyon%20-%20Hall%201%20&label2=Arles&listeCodesMode=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9&origineCP=75000&destinationCP=13104,13123,13129,13200,13280), but I don't know whether it's feasible to do so.  Plus it requires two connections.

Comment: SNCF-Connect will only find long distance trains departing from CDG. The trip seems feasible if you go by local transport to the city centre and take a train from there. It may also be a bit faster to take the train to Avignon and then a taxi from there.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Very unlikely... in all green conditions (very rare on RER B), a CDG-GDL is a 45min transfer. A taxi is similar

Comment: Another alternative is to get to Nîmes Pont du Gard (TGV station in the middle of nowhere, but 30 minutes from Arles by the road) or maybe Nîmes Centre. There’s a direct TGV from CDG to Nîmes Pont du Gard et 11:59 arriving at 15:30, that’s probably the closest option, but it’s extremely tight.